# "Loop" not working in C#

Tags: c#, loops

thanks to the community here I was able to write my first program. However, I still need some help to improve the program:

```
Console.WriteLine("BMI Rechner");
        Console.WriteLine("===========");
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.Write("Körpergewicht in kg: ");
        int kg;
        kg = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Größe in cm: ");
        int cm;
        cm = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Geschlecht (m/w):");
        string Geschlecht = Console.ReadLine();
        bool Auswahl = false;

        switch(Geschlecht)
       {
        case "m":
        Auswahl = true;
        break;
        case "w":
        Auswahl = true;
        break;
        default:
        Console.WriteLine("Ungültige Eingabe");
        Console.WriteLine("(m)ännlich/(w)eiblich");
        break;
       }
        if (Auswahl != false) {Console.WriteLine("Eingabe wird verarbeitet");}


        double BMI = kg / ( (cm / 100.0) * (cm / 100.0) );

        if (BMI < 19 & Geschlecht == "w")
        { Console.WriteLine("-> Untergewicht"); }
        else if (BMI >= 19 & BMI <= 24 & Geschlecht == "w") 
        { Console.WriteLine("-> Normalgewicht"); }
        else if (BMI > 24 & Geschlecht == "w")
        { Console.WriteLine("-> Übergewicht"); }

        if (BMI < 20 & Geschlecht == "m")
        { Console.WriteLine("-> Untergewicht"); }
        else if (BMI >= 20 & BMI <= 25 & Geschlecht == "m")
        { Console.WriteLine("-> Normalgewicht"); }
        else if (BMI > 25 & Geschlecht == "m")
        { Console.WriteLine("-> Übergewicht"); }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

I made a switch thingie in the middle to prevent the program from crashing if a wrong input is given. It works and I get these lines:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Ungültige Eingabe");
        Console.WriteLine("(m)ännlich/(w)eiblich");
```

which is supposed to be my "loop" back to the options "m" and "w". However, if I enter m/w now, the program just closes, meaning that it doesn't work at all.

Is there an error in my code or am I just using the wrong command?

I apologize for my command of the programming lingo. This is my first time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what loop - I don't see one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be honest I don't see any loop in your code.

You could do what you say using a `do...while` loop as such:

```
do
{
  //...
}while (Geschlecht != "m" && Geschlecht != "w");
```

The `do...while` loop will check after the each iteration (not before, meaning it will always enter in the loop at least once). In this case the condition says that it will loop as long as `Geschlecht` is not "m" and is not "w".

Applying this to your code, you will get:

```
//...
bool Auswahl = false;
string Geschlecht;
do
{
    Console.Write("Geschlecht (m/w):");
    Geschlecht = Console.ReadLine();

    switch(Geschlecht)
    {
        case "m":
            Auswahl = true;
            break;
        case "w":
            Auswahl = true;
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Ungültige Eingabe");
            Console.WriteLine("(m)ännlich/(w)eiblich");
            break;
    }
}while (Geschlecht != "m" && Geschlecht != "w");

if (Auswahl != false) {Console.WriteLine("Eingabe wird verarbeitet");}
//etc...
```

Please notice I have taken two variable out of the loop, those are `Auswahl` and `Geschlecht`. The reason is because both are needed to be available outside of the loop, in particular `Geschlecht` is needed in the conditional.

---

[Jimmy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25071/jimmy) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582504/loop-not-working-in-c-sharp/19582629?noredirect=1#comment29063656_19582629) that it is possible to do this in such way that `Auswahl` is no longer needed... here is one way to do it (as valid as any other):

```
//...
Console.Write("Geschlecht (m/w):");
string Geschlecht = Console.ReadLine();
while (Geschlecht != "m" && Geschlecht != "w");
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ungültige Eingabe");
    Console.WriteLine("(m)ännlich/(w)eiblich");
    Console.Write("Geschlecht (m/w):");
    Geschlecht = Console.ReadLine();
}
Console.WriteLine("Eingabe wird verarbeitet");
//etc...
```

In this case we have a `while` loop, in code inside the loop will only execute if the condition is met (that is, the condition is verified before each iteration).

You may also consider to have a different data type for Geschlecht since the only valid values it has are "m" and "w"... but I digress.

---

I want to suggest the entry [C# Loops Constructs at dotnetperls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/loop) as an introducion to the different kinds of loops in C#.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I don't think what I did was "looping" either. That's why I put Loop in the title in "". It was the only word I could think of that fits the description of what I need.

Comment: Also worth noting: by having good loop conditions, you can eliminate Auswahl completely.  If the loop exits, then a valid selection was made.